Intermediate disc efficiency with induction stove
I am going to move soon into a house which comes with an induction stove.
The major part of my cookware is stainless steel non compatible with induction stove, and being from a high range brand, I am reluctant to replace it completely, so I considered using the intermediate discs which are available on the market.
A friend who has been in a similar situation told me that they were not satisfied with how the disc performed, just gave up and changed the cookware.
Do different brands or make of the discs have different performances in term of effective heat transfer?

'the disk' suggests that they only have one... but I would think that they would need them in different sizes to match the size of the pan being used.  And if you have a round cast iron griddle, I suspect that will do what the disks will do (although slightly oversized because of the lip on it)

So is your question about efficiency (as the title implies, though it's not a question, quite) or satisfaction with performance (seems to be the question in the body?) Please [edit] to clarify what you are actually asking.

"cookware is stainless steel non compatible with induction stove" - most stainless steel cookware is magnetic and compatible with induction. Are you sure your cookware is not compatible? Checking with a magnet is a decent test. This is more of a problem with aluminum or copper cookware, not stainless steel

@EliIser yes, I am sure. Did the magnet test to confirm, the magnet doesn't react.

Buying an intermediary disk is a lot cheaper than buying all new cookware just because maybe it won't work well.  If it does work good enough, then you saved a lot of money.  If it doesn't, then now you have another bit of mass to smooth out oven temperature fluctuations.

@EliIser I also have stainless that doesn't work on induction - and aluminium that does (I didn't notice the steel inset into the base until I needed it, on a set of pans bought to use on gas). @ L. Dutch can you borrow an induction stove to double check yours won't work?

Any efficiency to be gained by induction .vs. electric resistance will be lost, as the intermediate disk is effectively equivalent to a solid-top electric resistance stovetop element; it's being heated by induction rather than resistance, but it's heating your pot and the air exactly as such a disc element does.
Such elements (so, presumably the disc as well) have a good deal of thermal inertia, so there's lag in heating up, and also lag in reducing the temperature if it gets too hot (remove the pot and wait for it to cool, or burning/boiling over is pretty much guaranteed if you've overshot the temperature/heat setting.)

If you cook with a solid-element resistance stove now, it might well
be rather similar. As with such elements, if either the disc or the pot bottom are (or become via warping) not flat so they maintain good contact, heating becomes significantly slower and less even.)
If you use a coil-resistance stove now, it will be laggy by comparison.
If you're now cooking with gas, unless you also have considerable
experience (which you remember) cooking with a resistance electric,
you'd probably be better off buying some induction pots, or you'll be
in for a steep (and annoying) learning curve. [I grew up with gas and have learned to cook on resistance electric, so I know that one. I haven't yearned for a gas stove in a while now. Early on, I was Not Happy.]

With suitable pots, an induction stove gets about as close to gas stove responsiveness as electricity can (and has a few useful tricks up its sleeve gas doesn't, in the usual induction stove, such as temperature targeting.)

Is coil resistance stove the same as glass ceramic stove? I.e. red hot heating elements which transfer heat via radiation instead of conduction.

resistance heat is 100% efficient in term of making heat, whereas a lot of induction power and power before induction (conversion) will be lost in the setup described, so it will be less than  "effectively equivalent" than a solid-top.

Resistance heat is NOT 100% efficient at getting heat into the food or pot. Actual experimentation has shown that induction is about 15% more efficient at heating food than electric resistance elements are. Heat  is made, but if it's delivered to places other than the pot, it's wasted.

Compared to a solid resistive stove (the horribly slow sort that don't get hot enough to glow) an intermediate disc would be better, and probably more efficient as those stoves take a lot of heating up which is then wasted at the end of cooking. Of course they're not very common, only really seen when whoever is choosing it isn't going to cook on it. A thin disc might be quite interesting for some edge cases
